# NUnit failing to reference Moq, only on projects

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, nunit, moq

I have a test assembly. If I load that test assembly into NUnit, all tests succeed.

If I then save that test as a project, I start getting 159 errors with a reference to Moq.

The project file looks like this

```
<NUnitProject>
  <Settings activeconfig="Default" />
  <Config name="Default" binpathtype="Auto">
    <assembly path="My.Assembly.Name.dll" />
  </Config>
</NUnitProject>
```

The error is

```
My.Test.Name:
System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly
'Moq, Version=4.0.812.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' or
one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

The error itself is fair enough. We're using v4.0.10827 from NuGet, so you wouldn't expect it to find v4.0.812.4. The question is: why is it looking for that, and why only when I use a .nunit project file?

The Test assembly is not referencing an older version, and no other assembly in the solution is referencing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to rename the .nunit project file to My.Assembly.Name.dll.nunit, I have issues with .nunit projects not finding app.config files for the assemblies under test and that's how I solved it.